# Is the href attribute needed for anchor to display as block on IOS?

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm having some trouble with an anchor tag that does not have an href attribute. It seems to display fine on all browsers/devices except for on ios, where it seems like display:block isn't working or something. Anchor tags with href attribute seem to be fine though.

Here is the HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="mailto:email@email.com" class="yellow-button" name="return">
        email@email.com
    </a>
</p>
<p>
    <a class="yellow-button" name="return">
        012345678900
    </a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.yellow-button {
        background-color: #ffd959;
        color: #333 !important;
        padding: 8px 16px 9.6px 16px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
        transition: all 0.1s;
    }
```

And here is a screencap of the error:
[image]

Any idea of what i'm doing wrong here?

Edit: I'm ideally looking for some way to correct this using CSS only. And/or figuring out why ios displays this error

Comment: why not use a span? also the name attribute is now obsolete in html5: http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html

Comment: Absolete? Looks like they're calling href an attribute in the link you provided. Anyway, that's beside the point. I'm not using a span because of the CMS i'm using. It would make for a more confusing interface for the user and i think this can be sorted with CSS. Just not sure how.

Comment: Anchor element is used to represent some hyperlink of link on local page's elements (using `href="#elelment-id"`). According your css snipped you need none of that, so feel free to use span or i html elements. Also try anchor element with href="#"

Comment: Oh sorry @Pete now i get what you mean about the name attribute. Confusing myself here. Thanks!

Comment: @dajnz, thanks. As mentioned above i want to avoid using spans or anything else. But adding a href="#" could sort it. I'll keep it in mind. What i'm really looking for though is some way to correct this error through CSS